# How to exclude certain entries from a query [SQL]

Tags: mysql, sql

I do have the following issue: Let's say you have a table that looks like this:

```
"ExampleTable"

NotPrimID     Number
0             13
0             13
0             14
1             14
1             14
2             13
2             13
```

**Question**: I want to have an `query` which will deliver all the `NotPrimID`'s which do have the `Number` as 13, **however** if the `Number` of a `NotPrimID` is also **14** etc. it should be automatically excluded from the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use exists logic here:

```
SELECT DISTINCT NotPrimID
FROM ExampleTable t1
WHERE Number = 13 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ExampleTable t2
                                  WHERE t2.NotPrimID = t1.NotPrimID AND t2.Number = 14);
```

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the ids, then use `group by` and `having`:

```
select notprimid
from t
where number in (13, 14)
group by notprimid
having max(number) = 13;  -- has 13 but not 14
```

If you want the original rows, one method is `exists`/`not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1 
              from t t2
              where t2.notprimid = t.notprimids and
                     t2.number = 13
             ) and
      not exists (select 1 
                  from t t2
                  where t2.notprimid = t.notprimids and
                        t2.number = 14
                 );
```